# AngularJS error - is not a function for service function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Angular 1.4.9

I use "joomlaComponent" service for my purpose

```
var joomlaComponent = function( $http, $location ){

    functions go here         

    return {
        showAlert         : showAlert,
        showModal         : showModal,
        showIconPopover   : showIconPopover,
        isHomePage        : isHomePage,
        scrollToTop       : scrollToTop,
        scrollToTopValue  : scrollToTopValue,
        removeHiddenClass : removeHiddenClass,
        getElementValue   : getElementValue,
        loadUrl           : loadUrl
    }

}
```

and it works as it should do but today I've got stuck. I need one more function and while adding a new function "setUserDevice" into to the service

```
        var setUserDevice = function(){}

    return {
        setUserDevice     : setUserDevice,
        showAlert         : showAlert,
        showModal         : showModal,
        showIconPopover   : showIconPopover,
        isHomePage        : isHomePage,
        scrollToTop       : scrollToTop,
        scrollToTopValue  : scrollToTopValue,
        removeHiddenClass : removeHiddenClass,
        getElementValue   : getElementValue,
        loadUrl           : loadUrl
    }
```

Angular says joomlaComponent.setUserDevice is not a function.
And I completely don't understand what's happening, what I'm doing wrong as it worked like a charm before.

Comment: It helps if you provide the whole service... Try `this.setUserDevice = function(){ //return something };` and call using `joomlaComponent.setUserDevice();` P.S. I think you may be confusing matters by using the term 'service' as the code you have provided does not look like an angular service.

Comment: I know, it's just a piece of my code and I have the next lines at the end of my code:
app.factory('joomlaComponent', joomlaComponent); in order it worked as   a service. And also I have a call in my controller joomlaComponent.setUserDevice() and this call causes the error above. And it wokrs good with all my functions unless I add this new one

Comment: Ah, then you are referring to a factory, not a service. It really helps if you provide full code to alleviate the possibility of ambiguity.

Comment: I tried this.setUserDevice = function(){} - same error

Comment: the whole code:

(function(){
  
    var app = angular.module('emnApp');
    
 var joomlaComponent = function( $http, $location ){
  
  var setUserDevice = function( userId, deviceType, devicePlatform, deviceOS ){
   
   return 555;
   
  }
  
  return {
   setUserDevice : setUserDevice
  }
 }

 app.factory('joomlaComponent', joomlaComponent);
 
}())